# Compare two JSON responses that start with square brackets and return differences

Tags: json, rest-assured

We have two JSON responses both start from square brackets(`[]`). I want to compare both responses and return the differences.

Response one:

```
[
    "12",
    "13",
    "14",
    "15",
    "16",
    "17",
    "18"
]
```

Response two:

```
[
    "12",
    "13",
    "14"
]
```

I need the following output:

```
["15","16","17","18"]
```

I found so many methods but those only check if the responses are equal or not.

I tried the following method but this works only for those responses that start from { but in my case the responses start from [.

```
public class FlatMapUtil {
    private FlatMapUtil() {
        throw new AssertionError("No instances for you!");
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(FlatMapUtil::flatten)
                .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put("/" + e.getKey(), e.getValue()), LinkedHashMap::putAll);
    }

    private static Stream<Map.Entry<String, Object>> flatten(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {

        if (entry == null) {
            return Stream.empty();
        }

        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            return ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue()).entrySet().stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> flatten(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey() + "/" + e.getKey(), e.getValue())));
        }

        if (entry.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
            List<?> list = (List<?>) entry.getValue();
            return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object>(entry.getKey() + "/" + i, list.get(i)))
                    .flatMap(FlatMapUtil::flatten);
        }

        return Stream.of(entry);
    }
```

Comment: I think it's just comparing 2 List of String . Take time and search it in SO.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your issue? Do you get a list of strings or some more complex structure? Your particular example implies some trivial filtering where the filter predicate would just test for inclusion of item into some different list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the list functionality:

```
private static final List listOne = Arrays.asList("Jack", "Tom", "Sam", "John", "James", "Jack");
private static final List listTwo = Arrays.asList("Jack", "Daniel", "Sam", "Alan", "James", "George");
List<String> differences = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
differences.removeAll(listTwo);
assertEquals(2, differences.size());
assertThat(differences).containsExactly("Tom", "John");
```

Comment: Thanks! Alex .This solution is working for me .It is simple and clear.

Comment: Glad that you like it. You can mark it as answer so people can see that the question was answered.